# Is 々 commonly used and recognised by Chinese people?

Tags: characters

In Japanese the kanji 々 is used as a repetition kanji.

So instead of typing say 人人 you could type 人々.

Is this character recognized by Chinese people nowadays ?

For example instead of 谢谢 could I use 谢々.

Actually it's more of an effort to type 々 instead of the original character but I'm curious all the same.

Comment: the diametrically opposed answers might reflect a taiwan/mainland divide? speaking personally i have never seen it used in the mainland, and had never encountered it (or even such a concept) until this question.

Answer (score 7):

It's not common in publications or daily writings nowadays, but all people can recognize it. It often appears in the calligraphies or on posters. The writing space of those media is precious.

And some teachers like to use it in class.

BTW, the Chinese prefer the right one, the cursive style, in their handwriting.

The source of it: cursive 仝, the variation of 同.

[image]

Comment: In mainland, it was still relative common back in 80s, but disappeared since 90s. It can still be seen in hand written text, but not in print or computer. I doubt the new generation still know it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is rarely used, and I doubt many can recognize it. It is mostly a Japanese thing.

Comment: When I grew up in Taiwan, I used it often to represent repeating characters.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is only used in China informally when people are writing by hand. I have never seen it used in print.